# Laravel - Circle Ci use Vessel as container?

Tags: laravel, docker, laravel-5, circleci

I am running laravel project and circle ci for continuous integration, now the problem I have now is me pulling a circle ci docker which does not contain necessary tools in order to get started:

```
version:                2

jobs:
  phpunit:
    working_directory:  ~/test

    docker:
      - image:          circleci/php:latest
      - image:          circleci/mysql:latest
```

I then have to download php extensions, chromium etc, I would like to use https://vessel.shippingdocker.com/ instead, Is it possible to integrate this vessel with cirle ci?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, simply follow Vessel's Getting Started Guide: https://vessel.shippingdocker.com/docs/get-started/

This is nothing specific to CircleCI.

Comment: so @FelicianoTech should I still pull circleci/php docker image, clone git repository and then start vessel and use that? I was hoping to use that vessel instead of the circle ci docker image, but vessel is as composer package

Comment: The Docker image is just the build environment. You need some sort of OS and basic tools to run a build. The CircleCI PHP image specifically includes Composer so if Vessel is a package, then as long as that's in your composer.json you just need to run `composer install`.